# MongoDB Match DATE between FAILS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a match like:

```
{
    $and: [
            { $nor: [ { Meetings: { $exists: false } }, { Meetings: { $size: 0 } }, { Meetings: { $eq: null } } ] },
            { 'Meetings.MeetingDate': { $gte: ISODate("2020-12-23T00:00:01.000Z") } },
            { 'Meetings.MeetingDate': { $lte: ISODate("2020-12-23T23:59:59.999Z") } }  
    ]
}
```

and on Mongo I have meetings from 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31.

If I want to get only the 23rd ones, this match brings them but also from higer date like 25, 26, 30, etc...

What is the correct way to match date BETWEEN to get a specific date? (could be one day or a range...)

Here there is a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iSaJHY-kFfh) with a small example, but here works fine, I get all from the 29th.

I guess my problem is in my Aggregation. On the example I added MeetingDate on the root and in real life its a child array, maybe this is the problem.

```
db.getCollection("ClientProject").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "$and" : [
                    { 
                        "$nor" : [
                            { 
                                "Meetings" : { 
                                    "$exists" : false
                                }
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "Meetings" : { 
                                    "$size" : 0.0
                                }
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "Meetings" : { 
                                    "$eq" : null
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "Meetings.MeetingDate" : { 
                            "$gte" : ISODate("2020-12-30T00:00:01.000+0000")
                        }
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "Meetings.MeetingDate" : { 
                            "$lte" : ISODate("2020-12-31T23:59:59.999+0000")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "ProjectName" : 1.0, 
                "ClientName" : 1.0, 
                "ClientResponsableName" : "$CreatedByName", 
                "ProjectType" : 1.0, 
                "ProjectSKU" : 1.0, 
                "Meetings" : 1.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$Meetings", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$Meetings.Invites", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "Meetings.Invites.MeetingDate" : "$Meetings.MeetingDate", 
                "Meetings.Invites.MeetingStartTime" : "$Meetings.StartTime", 
                "Meetings.Invites.MeetingEndTime" : "$Meetings.EndTime", 
                "Meetings.Invites.MeetingStatus" : "$Meetings.MeetingStatus", 
                "Meetings.Invites.ProjectId" : { 
                    "$toString" : "$_id"
                }, 
                "Meetings.Invites.ProjectType" : "$ProjectType", 
                "Meetings.Invites.ProjectSKU" : "$ProjectSKU", 
                "Meetings.Invites.ProjectName" : "$ProjectName", 
                "Meetings.Invites.ClientId" : "$ClientId", 
                "Meetings.Invites.ClientName" : "$ClientName", 
                "Meetings.Invites.ClientResponsableName" : "$ClientResponsableName"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$replaceRoot" : { 
                "newRoot" : "$Meetings.Invites"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$sort" : { 
                "MeetingDate" : 1.0, 
                "MeetingStartTime" : 1.0, 
                "InviteStatus" : 1.0
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

cheers

Comment: Add the data you are working with to the question.

Comment: You need to give some examples to show what do you want to match and what do you not to match.

Comment: Just updated the question. I think the problem is in the Match of my Aggregation.. a simple match works fine.

Comment: Guessing from the query, `Mettings` is an array? If so, you probably need to wrap the date check in `elemMatch`

Comment: You can write the match even shorter: `{ "$match" : { "Meetings.MeetingDate": { "$gte" : ISODate("2020-12-30T00:00:01.000+0000"), "$lte" : ISODate("2020-12-31T23:59:59.999+0000")  } } }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not related with the match on Date, it´s working. The problem is that each record has an array of meeting and each one has different dates, so even matching the correct date, the rest of the aggregation, Unwinds, etc... will use the the full record with all meetings, thats why I get with diferent dates.

Here I added an extra Match after $ReplaceRoot and worked... could use $filter too in some part of the aggregation..

cheers